¿Qué tamaño de muestra es adecuado si tengo dos clases desbalanceadas?
Tengo un problema de clasificación donde las dos clases de la variable objetivo tienen un desajuste. Mi dataset son pacientes hospitalizados y la variable objetivo es si requirieron entrar a la Unidad de Cuidados Intensivos.



Clase
Cantidad
Porcentaje




1
6394
4.715


2
129214
95.285



Para balancearlas usaré un submuestreo de la clase 2 pero me surge la duda ¿qué número de datos sería adecuado para la clase 2? Considerando que en este contexto el número de observaciones de la clase 2 debe ser bastante mayor que el de la clase 1.
Como información adicional mi objetivo es comparar el rendimiento de SVM y Random Forest para resolver este problema.
